# js plugin is not working when change page with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using this js plugin(https://github.com/oguzhanoya/jquery-steps) for step form page. Normally when I write http request or refresh page, that page working well. But using with react-router link, js plugin is not working. li element is not changing to active class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's normal behaviour. What you expect when you used 2 different routing libraries?)
My suggestion would be to forgot all libraries/sublibraries with *jquery* part in name and use a *react* libraries for these goals.